# React Router Dom removes the url sub paths instead of adding the routing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an asp.net MVC application that serves the React app under the following url: `http://domain.fake/controller/action`. Here is the routing of the react app:

```
<Routes>
 <Route path="/*" element={<Config />}>
   <Route path="values" element={<ConfigKeyValues />} />
 </Route>
</Routes>
```

When I try to navigate to the values route using the `useNavigate` hook:

```
const nav = useNavigate();
nav("values");
```

In the URL, instead of adding the `/values` path, the routing removes the whole `controller/action` path and only sets the `/values` path. So instead of getting the url `http://domain.fake/controller/action/values`, I'm getting `http://domain.fake/values`, and this is not right.

I'm able to display the component correctly, and I'm not being redirected by the server, but the url is wrong because I can't share that since it does not exist.

How can I prevent the React routing from replacing the base path but adding the new path to the url and displaying the component of that route?

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app` in development mode? Also, is this a problem you are encountering after deploying your app?

Comment: I'm in production mode. And yes, this is happening after deploying the app.

Comment: Ok, are you using `create-react-app`?

Comment: It was not me who created the project but no, `create-react-app` was not used. Based on what i can find looks like they used a vite template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell React Router Dom that your application is served from a subfolder, you could use the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router#basename) property, which works with [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)  as well as [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router):

> The `basename` of the app for situations where you can't deploy to the root of the domain, but a subdirectory.

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/controller/action">
  {/* The rest of your app goes here */}
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
createBrowserRouter(routes, {
  basename: "/controller/action",
});
```

Side note, be aware that calling `navigate("values")`, without `/` at the beginning of `"values"` would take into account the path you are on and build on top of it as the [doc](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link) says.

Answer (score 0):

true navigate method inside `react-router-dom` will clear the sub path so we need to add it manually
but this is will be bad if you hard coded it
instead we will add it automatically

```
function YourPage() {
    const nav = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation()
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => nav(`${location.pathname}/yourTargetPath`)}>
              Navigate
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

we will save our sub-path inside the variable and add it to navigate method
this should solve your problem